# How to enclose label c#

Tags: c#, .net, label

Is there a way to end some Label? Example:

```
bool x = true;
bool y = false;
string z = "Hello";

label_x:
if (x == true)
    Console.WriteLine(z);

//LABEL END

if (y == true)
    Console.WriteLine("Y is not true.");

goto label_x;
```

How can I end the label without executing if (y == true)? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to make functions and call them.

Comment: At your leavel of expertise the use of labels&goto is stricly prohibited. DO NOT USE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create another label and goto that one. This is the kind of stuff that makes people discourage the use of `goto`. It can very easily lead to "spaghetti code" which is difficult to follow the flow of.